# ¿Cómo guardar hasta N veces datos una serie de campos?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente frontend, en el cual se guarda información de la persona (3 campos), posteriormente esa persona puede tener hasta 12 pagos (convenios) el usuario del sistema puede agregar los cards de covenios con el boton agregar cada que agrega se incrementa el name="convenio1 hasta 12"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información se separa en tablas relacionadas "convenios" vs "montos" se vinculan por el last id insert en PK vs FK, tengo el siguiente código en el cual se inserta la parte de convenios pero no entiendo como mandar 12 cards para los montos y fechas

```
if(isset($_POST['convenioSubcredito'])){
    // Caracteres a buscar y reemplazar
    $textoBuscar = array("\r", "\t", "\n", "  ", "   ", ",", ".", "$");
    $textoReemplazar = "";
    // Subcredito
    $convenioSubcredito = strtoupper(str_replace($textoReemplazar, $textoReemplazar, $_POST['convenioSubcredito']));
    // Titular
    $nombreTitular = strtoupper(str_replace($textoReemplazar, $textoReemplazar, $_POST['convenioTitular']));
    // Monto Promesa
    $convenioMonto = str_replace($textoReemplazar, $textoReemplazar, $_POST['convenioMonto']);
    // Agente
    $agenteCobranza = strtoupper(str_replace($textoReemplazar, $textoReemplazar, $_SESSION['usuario_pb']));
    # Sentencia INSERT para insertar la información del pago en tabla "pagos"
    $query = "INSERT INTO convenios(numero_subcredito, nombre_titular, monto_convenio, fecha_convenio, registro_agente) VALUES ('$convenioSubcredito', '$nombreTitular', '$convenioMonto', now(), '$agenteCobranza')";
    $ts = mysqli_query($mysql_conexion_pb, $query);

    $monto = $_POST['montoConvenio'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i ++) { 
        if(isset($monto)){
            echo "prueba";
        }
    }
}
```

Hice algo parecido antes pero para guardar imagenes usando un foreach con su respectivo key => value pero no entiendo como aplicar un bucle **IF** para que guarder las 12 veces bueno si como validar el envio de N "convenios", no tengo mucho codigo como prodran ver pero entendi lo de la logica del IF osea si es con un if pero no como aplicarlo

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto? Puedes por ejemplo ir guardando en un array y verificando cada vez si ese array no supera el máximo permitido.

Comment: Desde php podrias recibir esos datos por POST, y como ya sabes que se llamaran `convenioNameX` mediante un bucle `for` que haga el ciclo 12 veces comprobar si existe ese POST (isset) y si existe entonces ejecutar la consulta INSERT.  Inténtalo, y si no te sale pon en la pregunta cómo lo has intentado y en que te has encallado y que error te da.

Comment: La verdad no tengo nada, aquí si ocupo que me expliquen desde cero, pueden darme un pequeño ejemplo, creo que si he hecho eso del bucle pero no doy como puedo hacerlo con esto ¡Gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: Si no tienes nada no podemos ayudarte. Las normas del sitio obligan a presentar una pregunta con un caso específico, con errores concreto y con código realizado para que sean válidas. En caso contrario pueden ser cerradas o ser votadas negativamente. No se nos permite realizar código a medida (o no deberiamos). Mi comentario era para que lo intentaras al menos y no te cerraran la pregunta pronto.

Comment: Está bien lo comprendo, lo ando intentando, no comprendia la logica del insert de las 12 veces, pero ya con eso tengo por donde empezar ¡Tnks!

Comment: No pasa nada por hacer un INSERT 12 veces, una por ciclo, si es que hay los doce datos pasados por POST, aunque si eso te molesta puedes ir guardando las consultas en una cadena de texto, finalizada por `;` en cada consulta, y al salir del bucle realizar una [multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) en PHP con toda esa cadena que contendrá todas las consultas, aunque no lo recomiendo, porque si una peta te va a costar detectarla entre todas ellas. Yo prefiero una a una en cada ciclo y verificando que se han ejecutado correctamente mediante, por ejemplo, un try-catch

Comment: Hice correción total de la pregunta, espero me puedan orientar en como aplicar bien la logica del insert dentro del bucle, gracias por lo del multi query

Comment: Mas bien necesitas esto:  `for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i ++) { if(isset($_POST['montoConvenio'.$i])){` ... mira a ver si puedes continuar desde alli y editas la pregunta de nuevo con lo que hayas avanzado, si es que aun necesitas ayuda (quizas ahora se te enciende la bombilla y lo ves ya todo claro :-) )

Comment: Al leer tu pregunta con más calma, intuyo que **le estás tirando a PHP un problema que debe resolverse a nivel de base de datos**, pues con un disparador (TRIGGER) y/o reglas de integridad referencial podrías resolver este problema de la mejor manera. Con un TRIGGER puedes definir cosas del tipo: *cuando se inserte un registro en la tabla tal, inserta o actualiza otro registro en la tabla tal*, y con las restricciones de integridad referencial puedes mantener al día esos datos relacionados. Hacer esto desde PHP es trabajoso y además arriesgado, porque cualquier fallo creará inconsistencia.

Comment: hazle caso a @masterguru es un genio del php a mi me ayudo mucho y saque muy buena nota gracias a el :-)

Comment: Y también  a @A.Cedano el sabe muchísimo de MySQL

Comment: Por cierto si lo consigues resolver ponlo como respuestas para futuros usuarios :-) y toma información sobre los [trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-trigger-en-mysql)