# ¿Cómo funciona un Trigger en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-8.0

**Me gustaría entender el funcionamiento de los triggers en MySQL**, ya que si bien el concepto parece claro.

Por eso me gustaría saber algunas explicaciones a ser posible, sobre **los trigger**.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es un tipo de información que debe de encontrarse en los sitios oficiales de documentación, stackoverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, considero que este tipo de respuestas no tienen lugar en StackOverflow.

Comment: @Aritzbn conociendo bien la documentacion de MySQL me parece que la pregunta es correcta y aceptable... MySQL no es el mejor en documentacion ... hacen falta un buen ejemplo y conocer otros términos relacionados a los trigger para tener una idea o conocimiento general de su funcionamiento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para entender como funciona un ***trigger o un disparador*** debes hacerte las siguientes preguntas:

### 1. ¿Qué es un trigger (MySQL)?

Se trata de una rutina almacenada que se ejecuta de forma automática cuando se produce un evento

### 2. ¿Cuáles son los eventos que levanta el trigger?

- INSERT
- DELETE
- UPDATE

### 3. ¿Los trigger a qué se asocian?

Los triggers se asocian a tablas (los procedimientos y funciones se asociaban a un BD).

### 4. ¿Cuáles son las instrucciones de un Trigger?

Las instrucciones asociadas a los disparadores o trigger son:

- `CREATE TRIGGER`
- `SHOW TRIGGER`
- `DROP TRIGGER` para modificar un Trigger que se borre y se reescribe

### 5. ¿Cuándo se dispara un trigger - Momento del disparo?

- **BEFORE (ANTES) , AFTER (DESPUÉS)** (de la operación a realizar  : INSERT, DELETE o UPDATE)
- **Esto nos da 6 posibilidades :** BEFORE INSERT, AFTER INSERT, BEFORE DELETE, AFTER DELETE, BEFORE UPDATE, AFTER UPDATE
- En una tabla no puede haber dos disparadores del mismo tipo. En versiones modernas (MySQL >= 5.7.2) es posible definir múltiples disparadores (triggers) para una tabla determinada con el mismo evento de activación y el mismo tiempo de acción
- **FOR EACH ROW BEGIN….. END** Indica las instrucciones que hay que realizar con cada fila de datos

### 6. ¿Cómo funciona los alias NEW y OLD?

Existen combinaciones que no tienen sentido : INSERT con OLD y DELETE con NEW.

- **NEW :** Es el dato nuevo el cual se usa con INSERT o UPDATE.
- **OLD :** Es el dato viejo el cual se usa con UPDATE o DELETE.

**Por ejemplo :** Tenemos 2 tablas.

- Tabla **Articulo(cod_art,precio,descripcion)**
- Tabla **copiaArticulo(cod_art,precio)**

El código del artículo de copiaArticulo es `cod_art` de articulo el precio de la tabla copiaArticulo es 0.

**¿Cómo pasamos los datos?**

```
INSERT INTO copiaArticulos SELECT cod_art,0 FROM articulos;
```

Una vez creado nos pide que creemos el siguiente trigger : Hacer un trigger que cada vez que se modifique el precio de un artículo se debe guardar en precio la diferencia.

**Por ejemplo :** El artículo tiene 10 y se modifica el articulo a 5 pues la diferencia seria -5

```
USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS dirPrecio $$
CREATE trigger dirPrecio BEFORE UPDATE on articulos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE copiaArticulos SET precio=NEW.precio-OLD.precio WHERE  
    cod_art=OLD.cod_art;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/259)

Comment: *"En una tabla no puede haber dos disparadores del mismo tipo"*: En versiones modernas (MySQL >= 5.7.2) es posible definir múltiples disparadores (triggers) para una tabla determinada con el mismo evento de activación y el mismo tiempo de acción.

Comment: @wchiquito ya lo acabo de entender y lo acabo de modificar