# MYSQL - Usar el resultado de una sentencia IF EXIST

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy intentando crear un proceso que si en esa misma tabla existe un valor me haga un UPDATE de una columna y que si no existe me haga una INSERT. Para ello estoy intentando recoger el valor de la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT if(EXISTS (SELECT id FROM yyyyyyy WHERE peticion LIKE sentencia), 1, 0) AS result;
```

En una variable, para después usarlo en un IF para hacer una cosa o la otra.

El problema es que no se si realmente lo que estoy intentado hacer se puede hacer así o no. No se me ocurre otra manera de hacerlo.

He probado a crear una variable:

```
DECLARE xxxx integer default 0;
```

Pero me da error al hacer el set del valor.

EDIT:

TABLA 1
id - mensaje - url - location

TABLA 2
id - peticion - periodo - pet_total

De la tabla 1 sería coger el campo url  y mediante un substring_index busco el numero de sql que se lanza. Con este dato buscar en la tabla 2 en el campo petición si este numero existe, si es así actualiza el campo pet_total +1, si no, inserta un nuevo registro con los datos correspondientes

Comment: Que version de mysql usas, para poder ayudarte ya que existe una funcion que ya hace ese trabajo por ti

Comment: lo único que se es que es menor a la 8...

Comment: @exferos si quiere que algo se haga automaticamente en mysql te recomiendo el uso de [trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-trigger-en-mysql), con un trigger puedes antes insertar y que lo compruebes, pero para ayudarte necesito que añada la tabla que quieres modificar con sus datos..

Comment: El trigger como te indica Javier, es una buena idea. Pero si lo que buscas es un proceso, simplemente tienes que plantear una consulta de INSERT seguida de una de UPDATE, cada una condicionada según lo que buscas. El tema es que estas planteando la pregunta desde la solución que intentaste y no desde el el problema efectivo, para lo último, te diría que compartas al menos las estructuras de las tablas: `peticion` y la que quieres actualizar junto con la relación entre ambas.

Comment: estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @PatricioMoracho en cuanto añadas las tablas podre ponerme con el trigger y ya acepta la que mejor te resulte si el trigger  o el insert seguida del update como te han comentado arriba :)

Comment: Si nos dices *"un valor"*, *"una columna*" sólo podremos responderte en términos similares: Una sentencia con unas claúsulas y unas condiciones. ¿El valor de alguna de esas columnas es llave primaria? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Aca hay algo re importante que tenes que aclarar... vos vas a trabajar sobre otra tabla, o sobre la misma tabla???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solución con Trigger.

***Un ejercicio de Ejemplo :*** Seguimos siendo una empresa pirata donde reutilizamos los números de facturas si la factura borrada, ya existe en la tabla delito deberá sumar el importe actual a lo que existía en delito

Primero se crea una función la cual comprueba si hay datos o no en la tabla **delito(numFactura INT,importe)** .

***Función existeDelito :***

```
USE almacen;
 
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS existeDelito $$
CREATE FUNCTION existeDelito(numFact INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE existDEL INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO existDEL FROM delito WHERE 
    nFactura=numFact;
    IF (existDEL<1) THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF (existDEL>0) THEN
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Trigger codprov :***

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS codprov $$
CREATE trigger codprov BEFORE DELETE on facturas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE multa FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE existen INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT SUM(precio*cantidad) INTO multa FROM 
    articulos,detallesFacturas WHERE 
    detallesFacturas.cod_art=articulos.cod_art AND 
    OLD.nFactura=nFactura;
    SELECT existeDelito(OLD.nFactura) INTO existen;
    IF (existen=0) THEN
        INSERT INTO delito VALUES(OLD.nFactura,multa);
    ELSEIF (existen=1) THEN
        UPDATE delito SET importe=multa+importe WHERE 
        nFactura=OLD.nFactura;
    END IF;
    DELETE FROM detallesFacturas WHERE OLD.nFactura=nFactura;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/281)

Esto es un ejemplo ahora lo debes adaptar a tus tablas.

Comment: Adaptando esto al proceso me ha funcionado bien. Muchas Gracias

Comment: De nada amigo y si te ha servido no te olvides de votarla positivamente @exferos