# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un registro en un trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, trigger

Es un ejercicio de clase con el siguiente enunciado(Debo hacerlo con triggers):

***Si se realizó un borrado en la tabla PAIS, deberá borrarse el registro
correspondiente de la tabla PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS, en el caso de exista dicho
registro.***

Mi código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_SUPERPOBLACION AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON
PAIS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.num_hab > 90000000)
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS VALUES (:NEW.COD_PAIS,:NEW.NOMBRE,:NEW.NUM_HAB,:NEW.EXTENSION,(:NEW.NUM_HAB)/:NEW.EXTENSION);
    ELSE IF DELETING THEN
        DELETE PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS WHERE COD_PAIS = :OLD.COD_PAIS;
    END IF;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El país ya existe en la tabla "PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS"');
END;
```

He intentado haciendo la siguiente sentencia, pero no se elimina de la tabla PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS:

```
 DELETE PAIS WHERE COD_PAIS=29;
```

Este registro existe en la tabla PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS también.

Comment: No deberías resolver esto con un `TRIGGER` sino definiendo adecuadamente **restricciones de integridad referencial**. La restricción que haría lo que necesitas aquí es del tipo `ON DELETE CASCADE`, es decir, cuando se borre un registro en la tabla principal, se borrarán todos los registros en la tabla dependiente. Para más detalles y ejemplos [revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967), aunque está escrita para MySQL, el concepto es el mismo.

Comment: La profesora pide que se resuelva con un trigger..

Comment: En ese caso, conviene indicar al plantear la pregunta que es un ejercicio.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo realizar aquello?

Comment: Sí, eso mismo. No entiendo como poder hacer un deleting para que se ejecute el trigger, ya que haciendo la sentencia que hice en el post no me funciona, pero con el insert si

Comment: @Aphans te recomiendo que  te mire este post sobre los [trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-trigger-en-mysql)

Comment: Vale, gracias lo miraré a ver. De todas formas no consigo solucionar mi caso..

Comment: Else if también tiene que llevar un end if, por eso lo pusé

Comment: vale entonces no te he dicho nada

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿la base de datos está en PostgreSQL o en Oracle?

Comment: Esta en oracle, disculpa por no haberlo dicho antes.

Comment: Conviene que pongas la etiqueta del SGBD en la pregunta, en este `oracle`. Fíjate que al ver `plsql` me confundí y asumí que tu BD estaba en PostgreSQL. Por favor, ignora todo lo que te comenté antes con respecto a PostgreSQL, borraré dichos comentarios porque no aplican para tu caso.

Comment: Vale, de acuerdo. Gracias, disculpe es que soy nuevo en el foro

Comment: @Aphans no pasa nada amigo todos hemos sido nuevo Aquí y hemos cometido errores al principio como fue mi caso 

Answer (score 1):

Ya vi tu problema. No está funcionando en el caso del `DELETE` porque la condición inicial no se cumple:

```
WHEN (NEW.NUM_HAB > 90000000)
```

Eso es debido a que cuando se borra, esa columna debe ser encontrada con `OLD`, no con `NEW`. Por tanto, se resolvería agregando un `OR` con esa posibilidad, algo así:

```
WHEN (NEW.NUM_HAB > 90000000 OR OLD.NUM_HAB > 90000000)
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcionando (he declarado un mínimo de columnas en las tablas, y no he puesto ni índices, ni PK ni nada):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PAIS(
>     COD_PAIS NUMBER,
>     NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
>     NUM_HAB NUMBER
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS(
>     COD_PAIS NUMBER,
>     last_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_SUPERPOBLACION2
>     AFTER 
>     INSERT OR DELETE 
>     ON PAIS
>     FOR EACH ROW 
>         WHEN (NEW.NUM_HAB > 90000000 OR OLD.NUM_HAB > 90000000)
>         BEGIN
>             IF INSERTING THEN
>                 INSERT INTO PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS VALUES (:NEW.COD_PAIS,:NEW.NOMBRE);
>             ELSE IF DELETING THEN
>                 DELETE PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS WHERE COD_PAIS = :OLD.COD_PAIS;
>             END IF;
>             END IF;
>             EXCEPTION 
>             WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
>             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El país ya existe en la tabla "PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS"');
> END;
> /
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO PAIS VALUES (1, 'A', 500000000000000);
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO PAIS VALUES (2, 'B', 1000);
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO PAIS VALUES (3, 'C', 700000000000000);
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS;
> ```
>
> ```
> COD_PAIS | LAST_NAME
> -------: | :--------
>        1 | A        
>        3 | C
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM PAIS WHERE COD_PAIS=2;
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> DELETE FROM PAIS WHERE COD_PAIS=1;
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM PAISES_SUPERPOBLADOS;
> ```
>
> ```
> COD_PAIS | LAST_NAME
> -------: | :--------
>        3 | C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a416f74ad357ee4295902c45971a1105)*