# Error en trigger After Insert MariaDB

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb, trigger, backend

Estoy trabajando en una tabla Maestro/Detalle (Producto/Compra), la idea es que al insertar un detalle cambie el estado de todos a excepción del nuevo registro, pero al ejecutar lanza el siguiente error:

```
Error: Can't update table 'compras' in stored function/trigger because it is 
already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `t_inactiva_compra` AFTER INSERT ON `compras` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    BEGIN
    DECLARE _cantidad integer;
    #ACTUALIZO EL STOCK
    UPDATE productos 
    SET disponibilidad = disponibilidad + new.cantidad_comprada
    WHERE id_producto = new.id_producto;
    #REALIZO UN COUNT PARA SABER SI YA EXISTE DETALLES, APARTIR DEL SEGUNDO DEBE INACTIVAR LOS VIEJOS
    SELECT count(id_compra) INTO _cantidad FROM compras WHERE id_producto = new.id_producto and estado = 'A';
    IF _cantidad > 0 THEN
        UPDATE compras
        SET estado = 'I'
        WHERE id_producto = new.id_producto and id_compra <> new.id_compra;
    END IF;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Te falta varios detalles como el hecho ``CREATE trigger nombretrigger BEFORE UPDATE on tutabla`` Para saber ver tu fallo exactamente, te falta los ``DELIMITER`` Y ese error indica que por ejemplo si modifica la tabla compras pones antes de INSERTAR en compra pues no puedes ni hacer otro insert de compra dentro, ni update, ni delete sobre la misma tabla, sin embargo en diferente si que se puede., modifica la pregunta y te podre ayudar con una respuesta y te recomiendo que te mires este post sobre los [trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-trigger-en-mysql)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, ahora edité el codigo, es un after insert y que actualice todos los registros de ese producto en la tabla compras excepturando el nuevo que estoy insertando. Voy a mirar el Post que me recomiendas.

Comment: Te lo he solucionado. Mira a ver si es esa la solución @DanielFernández

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu fallo es simple básicamente no puedes insertar y ***actualizar al mismo tiempo en un trigger*** ya que si no se pierde el puntero, para solucionarlo es simplemente quitar tu ***UPDATE*** por simplemente un ***SET*** y se soluciona.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `t_inactiva_compra` AFTER INSERT ON `compras` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    BEGIN
    DECLARE _cantidad integer;
    #ACTUALIZO EL STOCK
    UPDATE productos 
    SET disponibilidad = disponibilidad + new.cantidad_comprada
    WHERE id_producto = new.id_producto;
    #REALIZO UN COUNT PARA SABER SI YA EXISTE DETALLES, APARTIR DEL SEGUNDO DEBE INACTIVAR LOS VIEJOS
    SELECT count(id_compra) INTO _cantidad FROM compras WHERE id_producto = new.id_producto and estado = 'A';
    IF _cantidad > 0 THEN
        SET NEW.estado = 'I';
    END IF;
    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```