# Trigger para volver un campo AUTO_INCREMENT - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

como puedo realizar un trigger, para que cada vez que se inserte un nuevo registro en una tabla, este actualice un campo que actué como auto_increment

tengo esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que al momento de insertar un nuevo registro en dicha tabla, el campo id actue como autoincrement del valor anterior, por ejemplo si inserto un nuevo registro el campo id seria 11 y asi, esto porque el PK de esa tabla es el campo **id_usuario**

entiendo que se puede realizar con un trigger pero en MYSQL no se como hacerlo

Alguien que me ayude porfa

Comment: Para saber como funciona un trigger mirate este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/529962/188518) que he realizado yo

Comment: En casos como estos lo que se suele hacer es: declarar `id` como `auto_increment` y como `primary key`, y declarar `id_usuario` como `unique`. Hacer otra cosa es sobrecargar a  tu tabla, recurriendo luego a prácticas oscuras para mantener un diseño mal pensado, es justamente lo que preguntas aquí: inventarte un trigger para mantener un auto_increment ficticio. Esto, a la larga, te traerá problemas.

Comment: @A.Cedano es decir el usuario quiere que se incremente el id, no lo había leído bien antes pero gracias a tu comentario lo acabo de entender lo que el usuario deseas.

Comment: @JavierG.Raya sí, OP quiere una especie de AUTO_INCREMENT ficticio, y eso porque al haber declarado `id_usuario` como PRIMARY KEY ahora no puede declarar la columna `id` como AUTO_INCREMENT. La solución es declarar `id_usuario` como `UNIQUE` y declarar `id` como `AUTO_INCREMENT`, no inventarse un TRIGGER para mantener un seudo AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @A.Cedano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene ningún sentido querer mantener una especie de `AUTO_INCREMENT` ficticio mediante un `TRIGGER`.

Si lo que impide declarar la columna `id` como `AUTO_INCREMENT` es que `id_usuario` es llave primaria, lo propio es declarar `id_usuario` como `UNIQUE`, y declarar `id` como `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

La definición de la tabla sería así:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     id_usuario CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     clave CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     UNIQUE(id_usuario)
);
```

Lo que debes preguntarte aquí es **¿para qué necesito la columna `id`? ¿realmente la necesito?** Se supone que, aparte de llevar un control secuencial, es para usarla en algunos casos para ordenar o filtrar. Pues ya está, la columna declarada así está lista y será indexada para que tus consultas con `ORDER BY` o `WHERE` que la usen estén optimizadas. Si no la necesitas para nada de eso, entonces deja la tabla como estaba, no te inventes una columna que no necesitarás.

En cuanto a `id_usuario`, la restricción `UNIQUE` impedirá que se creen duplicados, y además la columna quedará indexada, para cuando necesites filtrar u ordenar resultados en base a ella.

#### Recomendación final

Si es una tabla en producción, puedes modificarla con `ALTER TABLE`, pero **considera guardar una copia de la misma antes de ejecutar los `ALTER TABLE`**.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta +1, pero puedes añadir una modificación con alter table y así no perdera esos datos que ya tiene

Comment: @JavierG.Raya eso pensé hacer, pero para afrontar eso OP tendría que dar algunos detalles, por ejemplo, en la imagen los `id` empiezan en el `2`, entonces OP debe explicar si esos números deben ser conservados tal y como están (por eventuales relaciones con otras tablas) o si se pueden resetear, empezando en `1`. Sin esos detalles no me aventuro a escribir un `ALTER TABLE`, porque hay al menos dos posibilidades y no sé cuál de las dos conviene a OP.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la aclaración :-)

Comment: De nada @JavierG.Raya. De todos modos, si OP explica esos detalles, podré aportar el `ALTER TABLE` adecuado. Saludos y esperamos lo que nos diga OP.