# Actualizar todas las fechas de todas las tablas que tengan fecha "0000-00-00"

Tags: mysql

En la base de datos en la que estoy trabajando existen varias tablas que almacenan fechas, y varios de los registros iniciales tienen fechas `0000-00-00`.

Me asignaron la tarea de cambiar todas estas fechas por `NULL`. Sin embargo, como son varias tablas, y además en algunas hay incluso más de una columna que almacena fechas, me preguntaba si existía una forma más fácil de hacer esto que a mano.

¿Existe algo así como `UPDATE` que afecte a todas las tablas, y que solo afecte a las columnas `DATE` y `DATETIME` con fecha `0000-00-00`?

Gracias de ante mano.

EDIT: No me refiero a usar un `UPDATE` por cada tabla, cambiando el nombre de la tabla y los campos para cada caso (de hecho, a eso me refiero cuando digo **hacerlo a mano**), sino a usar alguna instrucción especifica que apunte a todas las tablas y a todas las columnas que son `DATE`/`DATETIME`.

Además, y por lo que se me comento, este problema ya se soluciono y ya no se registran fechas así, pero los primeros registros que se crearon cuando el sistema empezó a usarse se crearon con esas fechas, y son esos registros los que quieren que afecte.

Sin embargo, en el tiempo entre que hice la pregunta y volví a ver los comentarios, ya he acabado con la tarea, así que supongo que fue más rapido haberlo hecho a mano, eh. Gracias por su ayuda de todas formas.

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET column=new_value WHERE column=old_value`. Es algo básico de SQL. No?

Comment: En cualquier caso, te comento que aunque actualices los registros que ya hay, si la programación que almacena datos no lo tiene en cuenta volverán a aparecer más fechas `0000-00-00`, así que quizá no llegará con arreglarlo directamente sobre la base de datos

Comment: *...de hacer esto que a mano*. Las bases de datos existen precisamente para no tener que hacer esto de forma manual. Para ello está el [Lenguaje SQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/)

Comment: Podrias haber realizado una funcion que modificada eso o un [trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-trigger-en-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Primero deberías aclarar que motor estás usando.
No, no se puede (dentro de los límites de SQL). A lo sumo podés armar un procedere para updatear tabla x tabla al estilo:

```
  BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLA_A   SET FECHA= NULL WHERE FECHA='0000-00-00';
    UPDATE TABLA_B   SET FECHA= NULL WHERE FECHA='0000-00-00';
  END
```

Por otro lado, y para futuros casos, podrías analizar una correcta configuración de la base de datos. Por ej. en mysql tenes los modes:

NO_ZERO_DATE , para no aceptar inserts en dates con valores "0000-00-00".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Y también analizar que proceso está generando esos "0000-00-00", ya que esto significa que el motor está recibiendo valores incorrectos para dichas columnas.