# Crear sentencia UPDATE desde PHP a Tabla SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, update

Tengo una tabla donde aloja las calificaciones de mis alumnos, en mi PHP yo realizo el calculo del promedio de las calificaciones de la siguiente manera:

```
$ori_p = padZero (round(($ori_1+$ori_2)/2));
$ori_p = padZero (round(($ori_1+$ori_2)/2));
```

> ori= Nombre de la materia

> padZero = sentencia utilizada para rellenar 0 a la izquierda del número

> round = redondeo del resultado

Yo quisiera que ese resultado que me lo imprime en mi php a través de un UPDATE se aloje en la columna del resultado de mi tabla

Comment: si es un promedio o sea un dato calculado, no te recomiendo que lo guardes en la base de datos, ya que nunca lo usaras, debido a que los datos pueden cambiar

Comment: Saludos @rpaillao lo guardo en la DB ya que en otro php se lo muestro a los alumnos

Comment: El punto es que si lo guardas y lo muestras tal cual ese dato no está actualizado, deberás implementar alguna manera de que se actualice automáticamente, mediante un evento en la base datos que se gatille antes de consultarlo, o mediante una petición a través de php con lo cual volveríamos a lo mismo.

Comment: pero en fin lo que requieres no es tan complejo, es solo a travez del resultado del proceso hacer un UPDATE en la tabla en el registro enlazado con el Primary Key que requieras, UPDATE tabla SET promedio=$ori_p WHERE id=iddelregistro a guardar, nada mas que eso.

Comment: OK amigo @rpaillao "deberás implementar alguna manera de que se actualice automáticamente, mediante un evento en la base datos que se gatille antes de consultarlo, o mediante una petición a través de php" sobre esto que me propones

Comment: un trigger BEFORE UPDATE en el registro correspondiente en la tabla

Comment: También puedes mirar este post de [trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529961/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-trigger-en-mysql/529962#529962) para entender el funcionamiento :-)

Comment: Porqué no usas AVG en base de datos?